# how to pass or reference model between asp.net core razor pages MVVM

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvvm, model, razor-pages

My MVVM core 3.1 Index page displays database data nicely from it's model using this directive:

```
 @model IndexModel
```

I launch a second page 'TOCPrintable" (for printing the exact same data but styled differently) with this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Print TOC" asp-page="TOCPrintable" target="_blank"/>
</form>
```

The problem: I am unable to pass or reference the IndexModel of the Index page and consume it in the TOCPrintable page.

My reason for referencing/passing the model to the second page is  I want to avoid coding the same database connections, calls, objects, etc.

IS my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between pages, or *State Management* as it is known can be done in a number of ways: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/state-management

In your example, since you are already posting a form, you may as well use hidden form fields.